# I cannot open Chrome after upgrading Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, google-chrome

I upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 yesterday, and there is something wrong with google-chrome.

When I type `google-chrome` in Terminal, it gives me some errors:

```
[26057:26092:0803/090313:ERROR:nss_util.cc(744)] Error initializing NSS with a persistent database (sql:/home/cyuan/.pki/nssdb): libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[26057:26092:0803/090313:ERROR:nss_util.cc(212)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: NSS error code: -5925
[26057:26092:0803/090313:FATAL:nss_util.cc(214)] nss_error=-5925, os_error=0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've tried to reinstall Chrome several times, and it doesn't work.
I also made sure the user have the rights to access `/home/cyuan/.pki/nssdb` the file there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these,

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

It works for me. Hope same for you.